# Is it possible to use a different texture image for the side faces of an object

Tags: edit-mode

I have an regular rectangular object I would like to assign say a one particular image texture to the top face and a different image texture to the sides faces (the bottom doesn't matter).
I have watched a video tutorial and got completely lost on how to select just one face to apply a second image texture.

How is this made possible simply?

I know how to apply a image texture to all faces of such an object but not two different ones although I can see how to add another texture image in materials.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the face(s) you want a new material on.
2. Click the top <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a new *Material Slot*.
3. Click the bottom <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a new material to that slot.
4. Click "Assign".

[image: Material]

Comment: Thanks Christopher.  I find my question has been closed as it apparently is a duplicate YET when I entered it a number of possible similar posts was listed and NONE was listed for the one IO now see is a duplicate of. Makes it very difficult. Maybe because the other one is 8 years old and the automatic search/check does not go back that far or it was at the bottom of the list instead of at the top of the list!

Comment: Hi Christopher, hope this post is still getting through to you. I followed what you said and noticed the new material was assigned to the edge faces however when I attempted to uv edit it did not show the new material. Once I assigned the new material to the edges I then marked the seam and then pressed u twice but that did not result in 'unwrap' displayed bottom of screen and when I selected uv editing (top of screen) it only displayed the first material.

Comment: The UV editor will show whatever texture is on the selected face. It only shows one at a time - If you select 2 different faces, each with different materials, it will display the texture of the most recently selected face.

Comment: Aha  I forgot to select face mode. I'll get there. I have now assigned my other material to the side face.  BTW I have opened a blender file where the axis are not central to the 3d viewpoint screen eg the x, Y and Z axis are to the right side of screen. How are they centralised?

Comment: Maybe try Shift + C?

Comment: Thanks I had to do that three times before they were centered maybe because they were so far off center?